# IntelliJ IDEA File Templates - Customize directory/package for Multiple Files Template

Tags: java, intellij-idea, file-templates

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to develop a Java app.

Let's suppose I have a **Multiple File** Template that creates a Model Entity, Service and a Controller.

When I use that template, 3 files are created `in the same location`. Assume that the Entity name is `Car`, then the files would be:

- Car
- CarService
- CarController

Assuming the following structure...

```
--+ app
  +-- model
  +-- service
  +-- controller
```

How can I define the location where each files gets created, so the result would be like:

```
--+ app
  +--+ model
     +-- Car
  +--+ service
     +-- CarService
  +--+ controller
     +-- CarController
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify folders in the file name of the template. For example your main template can have the file name `model/${NAME}` and below it you can define two child templates with file names `service/${NAME}Service` and `controller/${NAME}Controller`. When the template is used this will create the folders if necessary, or use existing folders if they are already present.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was looking forward to achieve